# How can create a menu?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create a menu with submenus. I created a bit of the code, and it is reading all my submenus, but I want to divide those menus in categories:

Example:

Menu - Submenu 1, submenu 2, submenu 3

How can I divide my submenus?

Here my code:

```
    function buildMenu(){
    global $ii, $array;
        printMenu($ii, $array);
    }
    $query= ("SELECT * FROM menu INNER JOIN submenu USING(menu_id)");
    $array = db_array($query, 'a+');
    $ii   = count($array);
```

Calling the function

```
 function  printMenu($ii, $array){

       for ($i = 0; $i < $ii; $i++) {
       $name = $array[$i]['name'];
       $suburl = $array[$i]['url'];
       echo "<li class='menuItem1'><a href=". $suburl .">". $name."</a></li>"; 
             }
}
```

Table information:

Submenu: 
submenu_id,menu_id,url,name

Menu:

menu_id,friendlyname,name

Comment: can u please update the question with table information (table syntax, dump data)

Answer (score -1):

Well I think you need to wrap up your PHP code with HTML UL, LI tags. For creating sub menu items, use your php loops as necessary.

Example:

`<ul id="nav">
    <li class="first-child level0"><a href="<?php echo $menu_link_1; ?>"><?php echo $menu_item_1;?></a></li>
    <ul class="level0">
        <li class="level1 nav-1-1 first"><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
        <li class="level1 nav-1-2 last"><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li class="second-child level0"><a href="<?php echo $menu_link_2; ?>"><?php echo $menu_item_2;?></a></li>
</ul>`

Comment: sorry but i think you didnt understand my question